# Preload database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, preload

I have been struggling to preload database in the android app.

I am making a dictionary app in which i have a database containing word and meaning.

I need to preload this database with the app and make the user directly start using it.

The only successful way i have been able to implement is making a db file externally and putting it in the assets folder and on app startup copy that file to the internal memory of android phone. But this way reduces the efficiency of the app. Copying such a huge database reduces the speed of the app and during the first time use the app becomes useless. i need a way to include the database right from the start of the app

I have seen so many android offline dictionary apps which come with a complete preloaded database which start working right from the first time with high speed.

Please help